# ASP.NET Core - System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, soap

I was give this Soap Service, http://thirdparty:2022/HrmService/HrmService?WSDL to consume in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API.

So, I used WCF connected service to generate it, I call it HrmServiceReference. Then I write this code:

**DTO:**

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; } = null;
}
```

EmployeeService:

**Interface:**

```
Task<EmployeeResponse> GetEmployeeDetailAsync(EmployeeDto model);
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private readonly HrmServiceServiceClient _client;
    public EmployeeDetailService(
        HrmServiceServiceClient client
        )
    {
        _client = client;
    }
    public async Task<EmployeeResponse> GetEmployeeDetailAsync(EmployeeDto model)
    {
        QUERYEMPLOYEE_REQ requestBody = new QUERYEMPLOYEE_REQ
        {
            EmployeeIO = new EmployeeIOType
            {
                EMP = model.EmployeeCode,
                DEP = model.DepartmentCode
            }
        };
        var response = await _client.QueryEmployeeAsync(requestBody);
        return response;
    }
}
```

However, I got this error:

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Implementations.CustomerService.GetEmployeeDetailAsync(EmployeeDto model) in C:\mypath\Implementations.CustomerService.cs:line 49
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

Then it points at this line:

```
var response = await _client.QueryEmployeeAsync(requestBody);
```

Then I have this in the Reference of the generated Connected Service (WSDL) in ASP.NET Core:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HrmServiceReference.EmployeeResponse> QueryEmployeeAsync(HrmServiceReference.QUERYEMPLOYEE_REQ QUERYEMPLOYEE_REQ)
{
    HrmServiceReference.EmployeeRequest inValue = new HrmServiceReference.EmployeeRequest();
    inValue.QUERYEMPLOYEE_REQ = QUERYEMPLOYEE_REQ;
    return ((HrmServiceReference.HrmServiceSEI)(this)).QueryEmployeeAsync(inValue);
}

System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HrmServiceReference.EmployeeResponse> QueryEmployeeAsync(HrmServiceReference.EmployeeRequest request);
```

[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HrmServiceReference.EmployeeResponse> HrmServiceReference.HrmServiceSEI.QueryEmployeeAsync(HrmServiceReference.EmployeeRequest request)
{
return base.Channel.QueryEmployeeAsync(request);
}

```
public partial class EmployeeIOType
{     
    private string dEPField;    
    private string eMPField;
       
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string DEP
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dEPField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dEPField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string EMP
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eMPField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eMPField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get this sorted out?

Comment: Do you have this in your configureservices method?
"services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();"

Comment: @Borntocode - No I don't have it there. More so, I am doing Web API. Do I need it there?

Comment: No, no need.
Sure you found a way around it already

Comment: @Borntocode - Still no way around it